# Casting null as an object?

Tags: c#, class, syntax, casting, null

I came across this code today

```
AsyncInvoke(OnTimeMessageTimer, (object)null, (ElapsedEventArgs)null);
```

Is there anything wrong with it or no?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Sometimes, you need to to this when the method is overloaded... to tell the compiler which one you are calling.  A null object is still null and it is safe.

Comment: Why didn't I check here before making a fool out of me on IRC?

Answer (score 4):

it probably needs the cast to resolve overloads